# Hacking an uploader to handle large files using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, overriding

Are there ways where I can use jQuery to improve the performance of a file uploader? There's a system where I am trying to hack to make the uploading process better. I am just doing some frontend override as I don't have permission to their server files.

The current uploader looks something like this:

```
<ul>
<li> <input type="file"></li>
<li> <input type="file"></li>
<li> <input type="file"></li>
<li> <input type="file"></li>
<li> <input type="file"></li>
</ul>
```

The downside using this is, you need to select images on-by-one and only limits you to upload 5 items.

so what I did, I added multiple="multiple" attributes in one of the inputs to let me select multiple items.

```
<ul>
<li> <input type="file" multiple="multiple"></li>
<li> <input type="file"></li>
<li> <input type="file"></li>
<li> <input type="file"></li>
<li> <input type="file"></li>
</ul>
```

By doing so, I was able to upload more than 5 items (7-8 items). One problem that I encounter is it CANNOT handle large files in a long session of uploading.

It can only handle images that can just sum up to 2 MB in total. But once the images sum up to something like 2.5 MB, it will keep uploading until 100% but in the end will return an error.

Are there jQuery plugins worth checking that you seem would be helpful? I need my session to last until it successfully finish uploading. I can only use javascript to override the process, nothing more.

Comment: It's probably the server, not the browser, causing the problem. Ie, it cannot be fixed with client-side javascript.

Comment: @Hamish I see. thank you fro your input. That's what I also thought...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not something you can change from client-side. Upload limit is set on the server then you have to change that threshold there (how depends on your Internet server, Apache? IIS?).

For example if you're using PHP you can set the `upload_max_filesize` property in `PHP.ini` to the value you need (10Mb, for example). You can do it in a per-site base with `.htaccess` file (just prepend `php_` to the property name).

If you're using IIS with ASP.NET you can change `MaxRequestLength` in the [`httpRuntime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) section under `System.Web` configuration (set the value in bytes to what you need).

Whatever is the value you set you'll always have a limit then you should notify your client too when it's reached (IIS for example just abort the request). There are several way to achieve this, the one I found more easy is to put the uploader inside an `iframe` and to check periodically the `readyState` property of the document (you may need to write a little bit more code of what you expect to make it cross-browser).

Comment: Thank you. The system I am trying to hack is in ASP.NET and I don't have any access to those files or neither to server. This hack is just for my personal use to make my life probably easier when using their service. It's kinda annoying when I have to upload multiple files and I have to select it one by one.

Comment: I just discovered that I can also upload ASP files but I'm not too familiar using ASP. Do you think I can adjust "MaxRequestLength" at the page level? What's your suggestion to my case? Also, do you prefer to answer it here or I just open a new question.

Thanks!

Comment: I was also thinking to upload a different ASP uploader to the server where I have control. But I'm not sure where to get a good one.

Comment: To upload a single ASP page is not enough, you have to change IIS configuration (see [this link](http://forums.eukhost.com/f15/increase-file-upload-size-asp-asp-net-9378/)). In case you can upload an ASP.NET full site then yes, you can do it but for a single page I really doubt they let you change the web.config file.

Comment: If the only problem you have is to make life more easy for you/your users (to do not select file multiple times but in one shot) then you may think to write a client helper application (it'll post to the server by itself any number of file but the single file size limit will still be there). As alternative you may do the same from another web site where you can change limit (but when it'll send data one by one to the official site then the one file size limit will be there again). Maybe many <input type="file"/> with support for drag & drop...

Comment: What do you mean by single ASP? I had tried uploading more than 1 asp files and seem successful. The only issue I think is I am not on the root acces. I am currently on E:\webservice\site.com\images\upload\. So I have some limited access?!. Sorry, no too sure about ASP. Thanks!

Comment: @Pennf0lio sorry, I assumed **ASP** = old ASP environment (VBScript, no .NET). **If you can upload a web.config file** too then you're done. Prepare a web.config for the directory you have access with MaxRequestLength property, upload the file and the web page for the uploader and it'll work for all pages in that directory.