# Image thumbnail and resize

Tags: asp.net

I have a code of picture resizing and image thumbnail working fine but it only support 3MB maximum file size. I want to increase the file size limit to atleast 10 to 12MB. anyone can do for me ? Thanks

```
   using System;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Configuration;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.Security;
   using System.Web.UI;
   using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
   using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
   using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

   public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
   {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
   }


     protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

   if (FileUpload1.HasFile)

    {

        FileUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath("Image/" + FileUpload1.FileName));

        System.Drawing.Image img1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(MapPath("image/") + FileUpload1.FileName);      

        System.Drawing.Image bmp1 = img1.GetThumbnailImage(50, 50, null, IntPtr.Zero);

        bmp1.Save(MapPath("thumbnail/S/") + FileUpload1.FileName);

        System.Drawing.Image bmp2 = img1.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, IntPtr.Zero);

        bmp2.Save(MapPath("thumbnail/L/") + FileUpload1.FileName);

        NormalImage.ImageUrl = "Image/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
        ThumbnailImageS.ImageUrl = "thumbnail/S/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
        ThumbnailImageM.ImageUrl = "thumbnail/L/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not the resize algorithm but the **maximum file upload size**. Change **MaxRequestLength** configuration setting in your web.config file. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590384/hacking-an-uploader-to-handle-large-files-using-jquery/11590470#11590470).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set maximum length of file from web.config file. Try this code:

```
<configuration>
...
<system.web>

<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600" />
...
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check the maximum request length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> Indicates the maximum file upload size supported by ASP.NET. This
>   limit can be used to prevent denial of service attacks caused by users
>   posting large files to the server. The size specified is in kilobytes.
>   The default is 4096 KB (4 MB).